# Example of using memmove in place of memcpy

Tags: c, memcpy, memmove

Difference: 
If there is an overlap, use `memmove` in place of `memcpy`

Q: Could you provide a practical scenario of any C lib function where an overlap happens so memmove is used in place of `memcpy`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one:

```
// len => array length, idx => index where we want to remove
void removeAt(int* array, size_t* len, size_t idx)
{
    // copy next values to replace current
    // example: {1, 2, 3, 4} => {1, 3, 4}
    //              ^ remove
    memmove(&array[idx], &array[idx+1], (--(*len) - idx) * sizeof(int));
}
```

**Edit:** Regarding this appearing in the implementation of a C stdlib function, that would be a bit more difficult to find, since each implementation can do their own thing, *and* most stdlib functions require that the arguments do not overlap.

Answer (score 3):

For example you need to insert an element in the middle of an array (in-place). This requires shifting the elements from the insertion points onwards by one place. This can be done with `memmove()` but not with `memcpy()`.

Comment: that is an acceptable, general scenario, but do you remember any from a library function?

Comment: @codeymodey: Have a browse of http://code.ohloh.net/search?s=memmove&pp=0&fe=c&mp=1&ml=1&me=1&md=1&ff=1&filterChecked=true -- there's a ton of real-world examples there.

Comment: @codeymodey: Here's an example from the Linux kernel: http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=LACPbnMYI2RxpXmGAuL1H08qbKk&cid=6NGO2C2fa5k&s=memmove&pp=0&fp=306559&fe=c&ff=1&filterChecked=true&mp=0&ml=1&me=1&md=1#L37